# How do I compare these ranges of numbers efficiently?

Tags: algorithms, c

I'm looking for an efficient way of testing eights.  What happens is I need to check if a value is eights and discard it.

The numbers I need to check for are:

```
8.8888, 88.888, 888.88, 8888.8, 88888.00                // 5 digits
88.8888, 888.888, 8888.88, 88888.8, 888888.00           // 6 digits
888.8888, 8888.888, 88888.88, 888888.8, 8888888.00      // 7 digits
8888.8888, 88888.888, 888888.88, 8888888.8, 88888888.00 // 8 digits
```

However, these are actually represented in integer form.  Which is the number multiplied by 10000.

So `8.8888` is represented as an int64 with the value `88888`, and `888888.00` is represented as `888880000`

There are quite a few values here to check.  My simple approach was to just compare each one directly from a table.  But then I thought perhaps I should maybe do something more efficient like masking and comparing each digit.  But my crude approach did not work.  It seems cumbersome and potentially a bit slow to convert to a string and compare eights that way.  This code will run on an embedded system which checks these values many times over so I would like it to be reasonably performant and easy to understand.

Note that I won't have less than 5 digits represented or more than 8 really.

This is what I am currently doing.  Not sure if it's the best approach but it works.

```
bool TestEights(__int64 rt)
{
    char rts[20];
    bool eights = true;

    sprintf_s(rts, sizeof(rts), "%llu", rt);

    int len = strlen(rts) - 1;
    int dec = len - 5;
    for (int i = len; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i >= dec) {
            eights &= rts[i] == '0' || rts[i] == '8';
        }
        else {
            eights &= rts[i] == '8';
        }

    }

    return eights;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "embedded system"? A digital thermometer and an MRI scanner are both embedded systems, but they have very different performance characteristics.

Comment: @Pseudonym - I can't tell you what it is unfortunately.  Performance would be similar to an arduino

Comment: Performance isn't really the main thing.  I just like nice and easy to follow code that minimises unnecessary steps.  It does seem a bit clunky to convert it to a string but it does work.

Comment: You're looking for one 64-bit number out of a set of 20. The AVR has a shallow pipeline with in-order scheduling. This means there's no branch misprediction penalty. So plain old binary search (even implemented as a tree of if statements) is a realistic option. But you should test it against linear search.

Comment: `888888.00 is represented as 888880000` computers excel in counting.